# Python version ambiguity on ubuntu 18.04 & ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, python, python3, python-2.7

I can't comprehend what mess I am in, somebody please explain what is happening here and how do I resolve it?[screenshot of command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3QDt.jpg)

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5

$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

Edit:
Output of command `type -a python`, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f8kk.png)

```
$ type -a python
python is aliased to 'python3.6'
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /home/jenim/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Note: I updated to ubuntu 20.04 after I posted the question and the things have changed as below,[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyNjY.png)

```
jenim : ~/Desktop
$ python --version
Python 3.6.5

jenim : ~/Desktop
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

jenim : ~/Desktop
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 15 16:15 /usr/bin/python -> python2

jenim : ~/Desktop
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 13 18:01 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7

jenim : ~/Desktop
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3694632 Apr  7 17:35 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

Now that I have updated to ubuntu 20.04, I wonder how do I have Python 2 still on my system. The release note of ubuntu 20.04 says it no longer supports Python 2

Edit 2: By following the [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy)'s comment I understood, python was being aliased to python3.6. So I removed the alias and Now things seem sensible except why does `which python` didn't alias to python3.6 ?

Comment: What is the output of `type -a python`?

Comment: Please explain what you did to cause this, don't make people guess.

Comment: It gives                                                                                                               `python is aliased to 'python3.6'
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /home/jenim/anaconda3/bin/python`                                                                   @Kulfy

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Still I would try to say what I have done that would have probably resulted in this. 1. Installed a new python version that was not shipped with OS. 2. Tried to change the default installation, following online tutorials, without really understanding much. @OrganicMarble Please let me know, if anything more specific, you want to know.

Comment: There you go. `python is aliased to 'python3.6`. So you're actually invoking Python3.6 while using `python`.

Comment: yes, @Kulfy thanks for that. One more doubt (sorry ;) ) why does `python` is  not invoking `python3.6` when i do `which python`.

Comment: You still have python2.x because you had it installed before and upgrading does not remove it. You can still find python2 in the `universe` repo. But why do you still have python3.6 instead of the python3.8.2 provided from `focal/main` after upgrading ?

Comment: I guess to not break anything, ubuntu does not change the link `python` when upgrading. Run `sudo rm /usr/bin/python && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python{3,}`. Then you can also remove the unnecessary alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3.6 is being invoked whenever you're calling `python` because you have aliased `python` to `python3.6`. The reason why [`which`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/which.1.html) doesn't see the alias is because `which` scans the `PATH` for executable files matching the names of the  arguments. In your case, `which` was actually giving the output for `/usr/bin/python`. From [`which`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/which.1.html):

> which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given  as  commands  in  a  strictly  POSIX-conformant shell. **It does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the arguments.** It does not canonicalize path names.